# Pandas - read_html with index_col not intended output when doing to_html

Tags: python, html, pandas

I may just not understand pandas fully but I am getting some unexpected behavior when using `read_html()` with the `index_col` flag set, modifying the data frame, and then attempting to use `to_html()` again.

Here is what I mean. I have this HTML file:

```
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th>index</th>
      <th>Avg</th>
      <th>Min</th>
      <th>Max</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>build1</td>
      <td>55.102323</td>
      <td>37.101219</td>
      <td>60.7</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I then use pandas `read_html` as follows:

```
dataFrameList = pd.read_html('empty.html', index_col=0)
df = dataFrameList[0]
```

This produces a data frame as follows:

```
              Avg        Min   Max
index                             
build1  55.102323  37.101219  60.7
```

I then have a small bit of test code that looks like this:

```
df.drop(['build1'], inplace=True)
df.loc['build2'] = [121212, 12443, 1290120]
print(df.to_html())
```

I get the following output:

```
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>Avg</th>
      <th>Min</th>
      <th>Max</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>index</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>build2</th>
      <td>121212.0</td>
      <td>12443.0</td>
      <td>1290120.0</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

What did I do wrong? I have tried to set the flag `to_html(.., index=False)` off but this gets rid of the build names (which I need).

My desired output (just so that it is clear) is as follows:

```
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th>index</th>
      <th>Avg</th>
      <th>Min</th>
      <th>Max</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>build2</th>
      <td>121212.0</td>
      <td>12443.0</td>
      <td>1290120.0</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a workaround:

```
df.insert(0, 'index', df.index)
print(df.to_html(index=False))
```

This produces the desired output (except for that `<th>` in the second row, which, I guess, is a typo?).

Comment: This works wonderfully but if you can add an explanation I would be extremely thankful.

Comment: `to_html` function is used to render tables. Try outputting the table in jupyter notebook, and you will see that there really are two headers, one of which is for columns, and the second is for indices (you can have MultiIndex). What I am doing above is just creating a fake column called index at position 0 and copying data from index into it. Then we just output it into html without the actual index.

Comment: yeah, if you look at the table it outputs, and your _text_ output above, they both look similar (columns on row 0, 'index' as a header to the index on row 1, actual index rows start on row 2).

Comment: @noisefield: neat, please edit the explanation of the issue into your answer (then it gets indexed and is searchable, unlike comments, and isn't prone to disappearing ephemerally).

Comment: (Was this a version-specific bug back in 2017? (which versions?) is it fixed now? is this working in the current version? etc.)